# Downloading Android source code

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I wanted take a look at the Andriod source and started the download process. I am having a problem in initialising the repo. I am getting a below error:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/repo", line 685, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/bin/repo", line 652, in main
    _Init(args)
  File "/bin/repo", line 184, in _Init
    _CheckGitVersion()
  File "/bin/repo", line 209, in _CheckGitVersion
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install git. The typical command would be : 
$ sudo apt-get install git-core